# Java "Connection" Class does not connect to the DB

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, connection, database-connection

I'm trying to connect my DB with a Java Application i'm creating. What I got so far:

```
public class DBConnect {

    public void DBConnect() {
        try {

            DBConnect DBConnect = null;
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ähs_system";
            String uName = "**";
            String uPass = "**";
          //  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uName, uPass);

            System.out.println("DB Connected");
        }
        catch (Exception Err) {
            System.out.println("Error while connecting: " + Err.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

It's a runnable code although i'm still able to run the code without any error messages if I change my uName and/or Upass. So based on that information i'm gonna say that it's not actually connecting to the database at all...
Anyone with a few tips or tricks I can use?

I've loaded the DB in services and I am able to reach it and add data and run other SQL commands within netbeans but that's basically it. I've also loaded the mysql-connector-java-5.1.35 driver.

Run Code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        DBConnect DBConnect = new DBConnect ();
        DBConnect.DBConnect();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Cannot connect to DB. Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Let me know if you need any furthur information!

```
Updating property file: C:\Users\Johan\Documents\NetBeansProjects\KiltenRos\build\built-jar.properties
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Johan\Documents\NetBeansProjects\KiltenRos\build\classes
C:\Users\Johan\Documents\NetBeansProjects\KiltenRos\src\kiltenros\DBConnect.java:23: error: incompatible types: java.sql.Connection cannot be converted to kiltenros.Connection
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uName, uPass);
1 error
C:\Users\Johan\Documents\NetBeansProjects\KiltenRos\nbproject\build-impl.xml:923: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Johan\Documents\NetBeansProjects\KiltenRos\nbproject\build-impl.xml:263: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Please print stack trace? and if possible please ask your question in clear words

Comment: please add your stacktrace

Comment: ... the actual creation of the connection is commented out. Of course it then doesn't matter what username/password you use, you're not actually connecting at all.

Comment: That's the Stack trace I recive when trying to run the program with both 
DBConnect DBConnect = null;
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uName, uPass);

If I comment out the Connection conn I dont recive any errors...

Comment: Without connection what exception you except?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error log is clear

```
java.sql.Connection cannot be converted to kiltenros.Connection
```

it seems that you imported the wrong class in the beginning of your class
DriverManager.getConnection(url, uName, uPass) return you instance of java.sql.Connection.

btw, change your local variable DBConnect to dbConnect so it won't has the same name as your class DBConnect and it will follow the java convention (lowercase on 1st letter of a variable)

Answer (score 0):

I've very little experience with MySQL, but I avoid using "ä" in a database name. Perhaps, the underscore isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

As per your stacktrace it seems you have not imported the correct `Connection` class. Delete the `Connection` file in your project and import `java.sql.Connection`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be a corrupted rs2xml.jar file. Once I reloaded it and it worked.